# What can we say about when Jesus was born?

Tags: quran, prophet-isa

What can we say about when Jesus was born?

I found the following

- For example the Qur'an states in [19:25](http://quran.com/19:25): "And shake towards thyself The trunk of the palm-tree: It will let fall Fresh ripe dates upon thee"

  This suggests that Jesus was born in spring/summer but it is quite feasible these ripe dates "appeared" out of season by a miracle of Allah.
- Shaikh Ahmed Deedat ([YouTube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=La2mpUj98eo)) argues that:

  > But According to the Bible as well as Qur'an Jesus Christ was not Born in December

  quoting the Bible and the above ayah.
- There is a discussion about this on [religiousforums.com](https://www.religiousforums.com/threads/birth-of-jesus-in-summer-according-to-quran.124361/).

Comment: As-written, this looks more like a call for opinion and discussion than an actual *question*.